# Как выровнять radiobutton относительно её подписи?

Tags: css, input, radio

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать выравнивание для `input type="radio"` (6 строк), чтобы кнопка была слева вверху (со смещением), а её описание — справа. Всё завернуто в один и тот же `div`, как на примере:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добрый вечер. Думаю тут просто можно завернуть каждый инпут с описанием в свой div, а потом сложить в ваш контейнер. Например, так:

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <input type='radio'/>
    <span>описание1</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type='radio'/>
    <span>описание2</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type='radio'/>
    <span>описание3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```